# Is it possible to display a Smart Folder as a stack in the Dock?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, smart-folders

I'd like to have my recent files at hand from my dock, preferably via a 'stack'.

I have already created a Smart Folder containing all my files that have been opened in the last 3 days and added it to the dock. However, **I can not change the display mode**: it is only there as a shortcut that opens a new Finder window.

**Is there any way to change this behavior?**

Comment: What version of the operating system are you running?

Comment: OS X Lion 10.7.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of your specific recent documents search, you might also like this alternative:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'; killall Dock;
```

This adds a **recent items stacks** to your Dock that has customizabile viewing options (grid/fan/list/automatic) like one is used to.

The right-click menu gives you the option to choose between recent **applications/documents/servers** and favorite **volumes/items**.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I need! Strange how such a useful is so obscurely hidden.

Comment: That is exactly the sort of workaround I was hoping to see! Wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see a workaround that makes this possible, but by default, the answer appears to be no, you cannot do this.

It appears that a "Smart Folder" isn't actually a folder, and the operating system isn't particularly smart about treating it as if it were one. It's just a text file containing a .plist with search parameters, but when double-clicked, it prompts Finder to open a window displaying the result of that search. The Dock, however, does not have that that layer of interpretation built in, so it treats it as a file (which it is), and when clicked, it opens the file, just like any other file stored in the Dock.